# When to use ON keyword in SQL Join

Tags: sql, join, natural-join

When exactly can I use `ON` keyword while using joins in SQL be cause I'm confused.

Also, could any one please help me understand different types of joins with an example.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-join.html

Comment: Just another example inside SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between inner and outer join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 1):

you'd want to do something like this:

```
select 
  tbl_items.item_name, 
  tbl_category.category_name
from
  tbl_items INNER JOIN tbl_categories
    ON tbl_items.category_id = tbl_categories.category_id
```

this would join your table named `tbl_items` to your table `tbl_categories` based on the primary key `tbl_categories.category_id`, which is linked to the foreign key `tbl_items.category_id`.

think of it as telling the db that you want to join two tables ON two matching fields.

**different join types:**

`INNER JOIN` returns only rows where the two fields compared in the `ON` statement match

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or just `OUTER JOIN`) returns all rows from the leftmost table in the join statement, and any rows from the rightmost table where the fields compared in the `ON` statement match.

`RIGHT OUTER JOIN` returns all rows from the rightmost table in the join statement and any rows from the leftmost table where the fields compared in the `ON` statement match.

Answer (score 0):

ON is required to match fields on joined tables.

check the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 0):

### Creating Joins with the ON Clause:

The `ON` Clause is used with Natural Join to specify the join condition, here is a more details written in form of bullet list:

- The join condition for the natural join is basically an equijoin of all columns with the same name.
- To specify arbitrary conditions or specify columns to join, the ON clause is used.
- The join condition is separated from other search conditions.
- The ON clause makes code easy to understand

Example:

```
SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, e.department_id, d.department_id, d.location_id
FROM employees e 
JOIN departments d
ON (e.department_id = d.department_id);
```

The Output:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | LAST_NAME | DEPARTMENT_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID | LOCATION_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | Whalen | 10 | 10 | 1700 |
| 201 | Hartstein | 20 | 20 | 1800 |
| 202 | Fay | 20 | 20 | 1800 |
| 124 | Mourgos | 50 | 50 | 1500 |
| 141 | Rajs | 50 | 50 | 1500 |
| 142 | Davies | 50 | 50 | 1500 |
| 143 | Matos | 50 | 50 | 1500 |

---

### Different Types of SQL Join:

Here is a good [Visual Explanation](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) of SQL Joins that would clarify the differences.

Thanks [@mihai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745672/mihai) for this article.

Comment: [Such Venn-like diagrams for joins are unclear, unhelpful & misleading.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642928/3404097) [See my Q&A comments here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549/3404097) All you have to do to see this is try to write a correct legend for one. Don't forget that SQL tables are bags not sets. Joins are on any condition & don't need constraints so at best the diagrams when explained address special cases and/or partial properties. Indeed the author of that particular blog post repudiates it in the comments. (Although their comments has more misconceptions.)